convert HTML5 input type date format to like this "01-Jan-2024"?
I am trying to format my HTML5 input date type date format to "01-Jan-2024". I have tried  placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" value="" and required pattern="[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}". Nothing working. Can you please help me how to format the date to "d-MM-yyyy" (like '01-Jan-2024')
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
 <label asp-for="OrderDate"></label>
     <div class="input-group">
     <input type="date" asp-for="OrderDate" class="form-control">
     </div>
     <span asp-validation-for="OrderDate" class="text-danger"></span>
 </div>


you'll need to use JavaScript to manipulate the input value. HTML5's  doesn't support custom formats. So that JavaScript is necessary for this task.

The date type format usually changes by default browser date format. For example i am living in Japan my date type format is Japanese (2024-01-Jan)

You could implement it like this:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Date Format</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="orderDateInput">Order Date:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="date" id="orderDateInput" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <span id="selectedDateOutput"></span>
</div>

<script>
    // Get the input element
    var input = document.getElementById("orderDateInput");
    var output = document.getElementById("selectedDateOutput");

    // Function to format the date
    function formatDate(date) {
        var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: '2-digit' };
        return new Date(date).toLocaleDateString('en-GB', options);
    }

    // Event listener for input change
    input.addEventListener('change', function () {
        // Get the value of the input
        var dateValue = this.value;
        
        // Format the date
        var formattedDate = formatDate(dateValue);

        // Display the selected date
        output.textContent = formattedDate;
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>




The HTML5 input date type only supports the format (yyyy-MM-dd) and does not support the format you want (d-MM-yyyy).
You can still achieve the desired format using JavaScript.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
